# How to properly use a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am making small simulation app, with base class named Entity and children classes named Herbivore and Carnivore. And since I am using SFML, I need to update them, deal with interactions etc, etc. My first idea was to store them in two different vectors, but that's not the most efficient solution, I guess.

Then I've tried using a little bit of polymorphism, but here is where I've utterly failed. I have one vector of pointers to the Entity objects. Here is its declaration:

```
std::vector<Entity*> entityVector;
```

While creating new objects, I call function from different class:

```
void ObjectFactory::createHerbivore(Sprite sprite, Vector2f position, 
std::vector<Entity*> *vector)
{
     Herbivore herbivore(sprite, position, m_GameResolution);
     Entity* p_herbivore = &herbivore;
     vector->push_back(p_herbivore);
}
```

Here is how I call that function in main Game class:

```
        //Creating new herbivore objects
        if (inputEvent.key.code == Keyboard::H)
        {
            srand((int)time(0) * dt.asMilliseconds() + 1 * 800 * entityVector.size() + 5);
            herbivorePosition.x = rand() % (int)videoResolution.x;
            herbivorePosition.y = rand() % (int)videoResolution.y;
            factory.createHerbivore(herbivoreSprite, herbivorePosition, &entityVector);
            (entityVector.back())->setDangerSprite(dangerSprite);
        }
```

And then I proceed to work on that vector, or at least try to, but it crashes by the first try to read data saved under that pointer. Of course, through the painful and long process of debugging I've realised, that I create a new object here, pass its address and then destroy it by leaving this function. So my question is: how to deal with it, so I can keep all of this sweet polymorphism?

Comment: @Youshua: You're pushing a pointer that in a jiffy will refer to an object that no longer exists. That's called a **dangling pointer**. It's very UB-ish, don't do that.

Comment: Also, instead of passing a pointer to a vector to be modifed, pass a C++ reference. And instead of that, if you can, just make the function result a function result. ;-) Don't be afraid of copying large chunks of memory: a vector that's returned from a function will (usually) at worst be just *moved*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **”** I've realised, that I create a new object here, pass its address and then destroy it by leaving this function. So my question is: how to deal with it, so I can keep all of this sweet polymorphism?

You can have a vector of `shared_ptr<Entity>` and you can create a new dynamically allocated object with code like `make_shared<Herbivore>(sprite, position, m_GameResolution)`.

The `shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer like `Entity*` essentially takes care of cleanup. When there are no more `shared_ptr`s referring to that object, it's automatically destroyed and the memory deallocated. We say that it's **owned** by the collection of `shared_ptr`s referring to it.

The `make_shared<Herbivore>` instead of e.g. `shared_ptr<Entity>{ new Herbivore{ sprite, position, m_GameResolution } }` avoids some inefficiency (an extra dynamic allocation) of the latter, and can also help to avoid Undefined Behavior where you create two or more such objects as actual arguments in a function call.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>     // for typeid
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Entity { virtual ~Entity(){} };
struct Herbivore: Entity {};
struct Carnivore: Entity {};

auto main() -> int
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Entity>> entities;
    entities.push_back( make_shared<Herbivore>() );
    entities.push_back( make_shared<Herbivore>() );
    entities.push_back( make_shared<Carnivore>() );
    entities.push_back( make_shared<Herbivore>() );

    for( auto p: entities )
    {
        cout << typeid( *p ).name() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that sounds amazing, but it's my first time using smart pointer, so I have some questions.

First, I should use shared_ptr<Entity> instead of Entity*, but when I just change declarations to look like this:

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity> > entityVector;

And this:

  void createHerbivore(Sprite sprite, Vector2f position, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity> > *vector);

compiler throws lots of errors. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Added an example.